# NullInjectorError: No provider for e! in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

main-es2015.6f31d328c9edc909ac03.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(i)[Se -> e]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Se -> e]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for e!

I get the above error only when I do --prod build.
FYI, the module is lazy loaded.

Any suggestions/help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You haven't registered one of your injected dependencies correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had done all that right. Found out Fontawesome version incompatibility was the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

Remove all the services from providers as you already have added `providedIn: 'root'`

OR try this

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        MyService
    ]
})
```

You have to add your service in app.module.ts

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had providers:[...] section in one of my components :)
When I removed it the error has disappeared.

Hope this might be helpful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the same obscure error message. In my case it was caused by a class which I tought was an Angular service (I didn't write it) . I imported the class and injected it via my component's constructor. Then I got this error message and couldn't figure out why.
It turned out that the class I was using was not an Angular service, but a conventional TypeScript class. So I had to instantiate it conventionally (i.e., without Angular's dependency injection):

```
export class MyComponent {

    // This is what caused my problem. "UtilClass" is no Angular service
    // It can therefore not be injected
    constructor(private util: UtilClass) {}


    // This is the way to use it
    const util = new UtilClass();
    util.doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Angular 14.1.1, the issue was that I created a new Guard and I forgot to add it to the Providers of my NgModule.

For more reference, check https://angular.io/errors/NG0201.